# will the rank of a projector matrix be equal to the dimension of vector space it projects to?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let the projector be the $N \times N$ matrix $A$. Let its rank be $r$. Let the dimension of the space for which it is the projector be $m$. Is $m==r$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The rank of matrix is the dimension of the image, and the image is precisely the "space for which it is the projector", in your language.